# core data migration by example

Tags: ios, core-data

I've read the document named [*Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html). But I still don't get many skills on this. So I want to post an example I met.

I have two entities `Rule` and `Instance`.
`Rule` has an attribute named `identifier`.
`Instance` also has an attribute named `identifier`.

every `Rule` has an unique identifier and every instance have an `identifier` the same to one of `Rules`. It is like a to many relationship between `Rule` and `Instance` (and it should be).

In new version of my data model, I want to make a to-many relationship between `Rule` and `Instance`, how do I do the migration?

Comment: thank you tkanzakic, I will do good on my format next time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured it out.
first, set these options when creating persistent store coordinator:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                             nil];

    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 

configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
{
   //other code handle error
}
```

Create a mapping model with Xcode, setting its source version and destination version.

Make a subclass of NSEntityMigrationPolicy,name it `MyPolicy`, overwrite the method.

```
-(BOOL)createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error
```

when this method is invoked, all the managedObjects has been create in destination context, but their relationships are not.
In this method, check what entity is the dInstance, and make relation for it.

With Xcode,in your mapping model, set The ENTITY MAPPINGS named `InstanceToInstance`'s mapping policy to `MyPolicy`.

this method will be called once for each Instance object.
for my question, I should do this:

```
-(BOOL)createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error{
    NSError *superError = nil;
    BOOL mappingSuccess = [super createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:dInstance entityMapping:mapping manager:manager error:&superError];
    if ([dInstance.entity.name isEqualToString:@"Rule"]){
        Instance *instance = (Instance*)dInstance;
        NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Instance"];
        fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@",instance.identifier];
        NSArray *result = [manager.destinationContext executeFetchRequest:fetch];
        Rule *rule = [result objectAtIndex:0];
        instance.rule = rule;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Then, the relation ship between Rule and Instance will be created when the app launches.

Also notice, relationships created by subclass of NSEntityMigrationPolicy don't need to set the value expression in xcode's migration policy editing window, just leave it blank.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful solution. My only problem is that I get a `NaN` for `instance.identifier` within the predicate. Any idea why this is happening? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021817/description-of-nsmanagedobject-shows-values-but-accessing-them-shows-nan

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you can use lightweight migration for relationship changes.

After you created your new version, simply change or add the relationship.

For more details look here [LightweightMigration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html)

All you need to do is add the option to your persistentStoreCoordinator method in your delegate.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

  if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
  }

  NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"YOURDB.sqlite"]];

  // handle db upgrade
  NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

  NSError *error = nil;
  persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
  if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
    // Handle error
  }

  return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Then, after you change the model and select it as active, simply reinstall your app.
That's all.

Comment: thank you, but the real thing is far more complicated than this, this is just an example to introduce me to manual migration.

Comment: Yes, it is. Just adding relationship.

Comment: @user465191 So why do you need manual migration ? I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: @shannoga Its required if relationship is based on values.