# Description of NSManagedObject shows values, but accessing them shows NaN?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nan, core-data-migration

I have found here an [excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14036989/92153) for creating relationships when migrating a model. I came across an odd problem within the model itself.

```
-(BOOL)createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSError *superError = nil;
    BOOL ismappingSuccess = [super createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:dInstance entityMapping:mapping manager:manager error:&superError];
    if (ismappingSuccess && [dInstance.entity.name isEqualToString:@"FTEvent"]){
        FTEvent *event = (FTEvent*)dInstance;
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:event.date_time];

...
```

There is an odd problem here with `event.date_time` I am expecting a value, but in the debugger it shows the value as `(NsTimeInterval) NaN` instead of the actual value.

However when I print the description of event, I can clearly see date value provided. How is this possible that it shows `NaN` when I do `event.date_time`?

```
Printing description of event:
<NSManagedObject: 0xbbb9b80> (entity: FTEvent; id: 0xbbbab90 <x-coredata://069BC324-2002-4DBA-879A-DC085C645903/FTEvent/p1> ; data: {
    "date_time" = "2014-04-10 23:00:00 +0000";
    "is_deleted" = 0;
    key = "4F6646FF-4110-427F-B2FD-3CFCAF777793";
    notes = Fdsfdsfd;
    rating = 1;
    record = nil;
    timestamp = "2045-04-11 01:19:06 +0000";
})
```

**FTEvent:**

```
@class FTRecord;

@interface FTEvent : NSManagedObject
{
    BOOL is_edited;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval date_time;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL is_deleted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * key;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * notes;
@property (nonatomic) int16_t rating;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) FTRecord *record;
```

Comment: How is date_time actually defined in the model.  Your description looks like a NSDate rather than a NSTimeInterval.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated the question with the model definition. BTW only strings can be accessed such as `event.notes`. But `rating` also can't be accessed which is int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found it.  It can be accessed as key/value pair.

**Wrong:**

```
[event date_time]
```

**Correct:**

```
NSDate *date_time = [event valueForKey:@"date_time"];
```

I was under the false impression, it would be using the properties on the model.